# Make Every entry in wordpress as post type ( or custom post type)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am new to wordpress. So i just want your advice on the following thing

I am doing a project using a **wordpress theme** .In my project I am having a form using which I create employee's entry, For which I created my own table with name wp_employees with field names *srno , empID , empNAME , Phone , Address etc*

Another Form creates entry for company's details .For which again I created my own table with name wp_company with relevant fields.

Everything is working fine. But one of My friend told me to create every entry of employee and company as **custom post type** , using which I can do the project sooner and properly.

Please tell me How to do all this using wordpress tables . How to add employee details as a post type. Same way for company details

**NOTE : Employee will have a secondary key to relate employee with the company details**

Comment: There are various ways to do that. one way may be: 1>create new custom post type either using plugin(CPT UI) or custom code.2>add required field using plugin(advance custom field) . if your submitting data from admin then it is enough. if your submit data from front end then analysis the table and way the data store on table  "posts " and post_meta" then create post. for coding search on wordpress.org

Answer (score 0):

The default post type of wordpress contains certain default fields that cannot be changed (such as post title, description, featured image, excerpt, author, date, comment.. ). But you can add as much custom input fields as per your requirement by the use of meta boxes. This is a magical property of post types.

> The meta boxes are such fields that allow you to add the custom input field of your choice (as for example: text fields, radio buttons, select area, text area, etc.)

We can use these meta boxes for default post type as well as custom post type.

As per your case, you can add meta boxes as per your requirement. For employees, you can create a custom post type employees that contains the input fields such as employee ID, Name, Phone, Address, etc.
Similar can be done with Company details.

This can be done by using any of the following two ways :
1. Using custom Plugins.
2. Hardcore function writing.

Since you are using theme, you can install new plugins that allow you to do so. The following plugins might be suited to your case:

1. [Meta Box](https://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/)
2. [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)
3. [Custom Post Type](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/)

If you choose programming codes then following might help you as well:

1. [Adding Meta boxes](http://themefoundation.com/wordpress-meta-boxes-guide/)
2. [Custom Post Types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Comment: For doing this, you wont need a custom table as the meta filed are stored in the meta column assigned in the default table.

Comment: Thanks Little Oars .. I went through this this link too http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/ .
But I did not understand how custom post will take care of my fields like name address phone empID etc ... 
While 'register_post_type' , there was no mention about how to add fields in a custom post so that I can later filter too.So can you please explain it with a basic example.

Comment: You just registered the post type under the name you wanted !! 
Now you have to add meta boxes on the view page of that new post type you just created. Go through another link (adding meta boxes on above answer)...

Comment: Hide all the default input type of the custom post and add new input fields (text, textarea, select, radio) as per your requirement.